# Selenium C# security error appears again when performing full page reload

Tags: c#, selenium, ssl, microsoft-edge

I'm performing a UI test where full-refresh of the page (a.k.a ctrl+F5, no-cache header) is required. Everything works fine in all the browsers except EDGE.

While initially handled, like so:

```
if (title.Contains("Certificate Error"))
{
     driver.Navigate()
               .GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink')
               .click()");
     continue;
 }
```

the security exception reappears when performing, this:

```
driver.Navigate().Refresh();
```

**Q**: What would be the best way to handle this case?

Comment: Why don't you add the code again?

Comment: Seems like a hack. Ideally, it would be great to solve it either by allowing insecure certs inside the Edge (manually) or some programmatic way (registry or driver option).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to repeat the code, I am not sure if there a certificate exception available for EDGE yet

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/how-to-add-certificate-exceptions-in-edge-browser/19726853-d730-4957-abd9-220a70c082c0?auth=1

But if you can add add your site as a Secured site in IE settings then it may work